# Set theory : is union of more than two sets possible

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is union of more than two sets possible? If not why please explain.

Comment: Yes, for any cardinality, it is possible to form a union of a collection of sets of that cardinality

Answer (score 3):

You can produce $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}}A = \{a|\exists A \in \mathcal{A}, a \in A\}$ thanks to the [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union), but (at least for me) it isn't that intuitive to use.

The intuition is this one: if you can build things like "$X \cup Y$", then if you want to build $A \cup B\cup C$, first you can build $D=A\cup B$ and then $D \cup C = (A \cup B)\cup C$. Luckily, unions are associative, so $(A \cup B)\cup C = A \cup (B\cup C)$.

Comment: +1 for reference to the actual axiom, so that OP can (with a little more sophistication) realize that the question is a little deeper than it might seem (and that the answer might be context-dependent, although that's unlikely to matter to OP at this point).

Comment: Note that with the build-up method, you only get unions of finitely many sets, while the axiom of union guarantees the union of arbitrary many sets, including infinitely many and even uncountably many.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we define the union of more that two set to be the set of elements which belong to  at least one of those sets.

For example if $A$ is the set of multiples of $5$ and $B$ is the set of multiple of $12$ and $C$ is the set of multiples of $7$ then $A\cup B \cup C$ is the set of integers which are multiples of one or more of  $5,7,12$

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, for example consider the 3 sets, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3,4,5\}$ and $C=\{5,6\}$.

So, $A \cup B \cup C=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$